# Associate physical USB slot with logical disk device

Tags: linux, usb, usb-flash-drive

I have an array of USB-storage devices (currently 14, but this could change) which can be inserted/removed in "random" order.

I need to write a monitoring program automatically keeping track of what is inserted where and which device is associated with it.

A typical insertion generates the following `/dev/kmsg` entries:

```
6,2146,143457970892,-;usb 2-4.1.1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 61 using xhci_hcd
 SUBSYSTEM=usb
 DEVICE=+usb:2-4.1.1
6,2147,143457998502,-;usb 2-4.1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0749, bcdDevice=12.06
 SUBSYSTEM=usb
 DEVICE=c189:188
6,2148,143457998509,-;usb 2-4.1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=5
 SUBSYSTEM=usb
 DEVICE=c189:188
6,2149,143457998513,-;usb 2-4.1.1: Product: USB Storage
 SUBSYSTEM=usb
 DEVICE=c189:188
6,2150,143457998517,-;usb 2-4.1.1: Manufacturer: SABRENT 
 SUBSYSTEM=usb
 DEVICE=c189:188
6,2151,143457998520,-;usb 2-4.1.1: SerialNumber: 000000000015
 SUBSYSTEM=usb
 DEVICE=c189:188
6,2152,143458003311,-;usb-storage 2-4.1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
 SUBSYSTEM=usb
 DEVICE=+usb:2-4.1.1:1.0
6,2153,143458005156,-;scsi host3: usb-storage 2-4.1.1:1.0
 SUBSYSTEM=scsi
 DEVICE=+scsi:host3
5,2154,143459012497,-;scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SABRENT  SD               1206 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
 SUBSYSTEM=scsi
 DEVICE=+scsi:3:0:0:0
5,2155,143459013727,-;sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
 SUBSYSTEM=scsi
 DEVICE=+scsi:3:0:0:0
5,2156,143459425631,-;sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 15661056 512-byte logical blocks: (8.02 GB/7.47 GiB)
 SUBSYSTEM=scsi
 DEVICE=+scsi:3:0:0:0
5,2157,143459426476,-;sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
 SUBSYSTEM=scsi
 DEVICE=+scsi:3:0:0:0
7,2158,143459426488,-;sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 21 00 00 00
 SUBSYSTEM=scsi
 DEVICE=+scsi:3:0:0:0
5,2159,143459427197,-;sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
 SUBSYSTEM=scsi
 DEVICE=+scsi:3:0:0:0
6,2160,143459469457,-; sdc: sdc1 sdc2 sdc3 sdc4 sdc5 sdc6 sdc7 sdc8 sdc9
5,2161,143459473702,-;sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
 SUBSYSTEM=scsi
 DEVICE=+scsi:3:0:0:0
```

while a disconnect elicits only:

```
6,2163,143469908844,-;usb 2-4.1.1: USB disconnect, device number 61
 SUBSYSTEM=usb
 DEVICE=c189:188
```

My problem is reliably associating `2-4.1.1` (position of USB slot in the tree) with `sdc` (device name I can use to access storage) even when several devices are connected/disconnected "at once" (it *can* happen!).

The only chain I see is `usb 2-4.1.1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 61` -> `scsi host3: usb-storage 2-4.1.1:1.0` -> `sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk`, but this works IFF `DEVICE=+scsi:host3` <==> `DEVICE=+scsi:3:0:0:0` which seems reasonable, but I'm unsure.

Do I have other strategies available?

Comment: I think you could monitor changes to /dev/disks/by-path or /dev/disks/by-uuid (if the device changes its physical port). They contain symlinks to the devices and are maintained by udev rules (depends on the distribution you are using).

Comment: @EduardoBissi: I will have a look, but AFAIK the whole `udev` essentially relies on monitoring kernel events so it should be possible to do the same. am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this, building on the hint from @EduardoBissi.

I hook on `netlink` socket just like `udev` to get the info I need (better than what I found in `klog`).

I wrote two small `class`es:

```
import os
import socket

NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT = 15


class KernelEventMonitor(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_NETLINK, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.socket.bind((os.getpid(), -1))
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.socket.close()

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            data = self.socket.recv(16384)
            if data.startswith(b'libudev'):
                event = {}
                for item in data.split(b'\x00'):
                    try:
                        k, v = item.split(b'=', 1)
                        event[k.decode('ascii')] = v.decode('ascii')
                    except ValueError:
                        pass
                yield event


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import re

    r2 = re.compile(r'/devices/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/(?:[0-9-.]+/)+([0-9-.]+):[0-9.]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/'
                    r'block/(sd[a-z])/sd[a-z]1$')

    with KernelEventMonitor() as monitor:
        for evt in monitor:
            if evt['SUBSYSTEM'] == 'block' and (m := r2.search(evt['DEVPATH'])):
                print(f'Device {m.group(2)} went {evt["ACTION"]} on usb:{m.group(1)}')
```

Note: the "same" event appears *twice* in `AF_NETLINK` socket, one before and one after `udev` handled it. I chose to use the "after udev" one so I'm sure any needed device is already in place when I generate my events.

Second `class` simply filters and reshapes events and is more specific to my USB configuration (I have several identical 7port USB hubs that in truth are a couple of 4port hubs with second cascaded on port1 of the first; this is obviously very specific, but I left it in to show how to handle similar situations):

```
import re

import netlink


class SDMonitor(netlink.KernelEventMonitor):
    r2 = re.compile(r'/devices/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/(?:[0-9-.]+/)+[0-9]+-(\d+)\.([0-9.]+):'
                    r'[0-9.]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/block/(sd[a-z])/sd[a-z]1$')

    def __iter__(self):
        def _get_index(t):
            return

        for event in super().__iter__():
            if event['SUBSYSTEM'] == 'block':
                m = SDMonitor.r2.search(event['DEVPATH'])
                if m:
                    try:
                        act = {'add': '+', 'remove': '-'}[event["ACTION"]]
                        dev = m.group(3)
                        row = int(m.group(1))
                        col = {'1.1': 1, '1.2': 2, '1.3': 3, '1.4': 4, '2': 5, '3': 6, '4': 7}[m.group(2)]
                        evt = (act, dev, row, col)
                        yield evt
                    except (KeyError, ValueError):
                        print(f'** Bad entry ** {m.group(3)} went {event["ACTION"]} on usb:{m.group(1)}.{m.group(2)}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with SDMonitor() as monitor:
        for a, d, r, c in monitor:
            print(f'{a} {d} --> ({r}, {c})')
```

I am quite happy with result, but I won't accept my own answer for a few days to see if someone can come up with a better solution.